# UITableViewCell AccessoryView not displayed properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableviewCell with a UISwitch in the accessoryView and it is displayed properly at runtime, but as soon as I rotate the device, the switch isn't anymore at the right place.
[image: the wrong place for accessoryView]

I could use constraints and not use the accessoryView, but I thought I could use this field..
Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks !

EDIT : 
here is the configuration in Interface Builder :
[image]

EDIT 2 : 
I used a Custom cell : 
[image]

with initialization on the default properties :

```
self.textLabel.font = [UIFont preferredDynamicFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody fontSize:16.0];
self.backgroundColor = self.contentView.backgroundColor;

self.textLabel.text = item.title;
self.selectedImage = item.imageSelected;
self.unselectedImage = item.image;
self.imageView.image = self.unselectedImage;
// if I do it programmatically
self.accessoryView = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
```

I don't set constraints at all, because I use the default properties..

Comment: I don't have code for my switch, I used Interface builder and linked the switch to the accessoryView of the UITableViewCell

Comment: Maybe it is a bug or whatever, try to set it from the code

Comment: I also try it with self.accessoryView = [[UISwitch alloc] init]; but it is the same.. I think the bug is on the accessoryView itself..

Comment: Is that totally custom cell?

Comment: Did you set the constraints n the table view itself?

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? From what I can tell, the constraints are being ignored, or not applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like if you create the `accessoryView` and the `editingAccessoryView` in code and set it, everything works great!

If you try to set them in the `UIStoryBoard`, the `UITableViewCell` will remove the `constraints` after they fade away the first time, and it *won't* add them back. It's a shame, but hopefully they change it in a later version.

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 3):

I'm just having the same issue as you.

Here are my observations:

- If you set the accessoryView by code, it's always OK, whether the cell is selected or not, on both iOS 7 and iOS 8.
- If you set the accessoryView by IB, the accessoryView moves to the top left corner **after the first selection of the cell, and only on iOS 8**.

I don't know if the issue is from IB or the way cells layout the accessory view on iOS 8 but so far the workaround is simple: always set the accessoryView by code to avoid unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout (probably), you should setup **constraints** first.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this issue currently, I think I have an explanation of what might be happening here:

This is an issue with the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property on the view. From Apple's documentation, particularly relevant bits in bold:

> If this property’s value is YES, the system creates a set of
> constraints that duplicate the behavior specified by the view’s
> autoresizing mask. This also lets you modify the view’s size and
> location using the view’s frame, bounds, or center properties,
> allowing you to create a static, frame-based layout within Auto
> Layout. **Note that the autoresizing mask constraints fully specify the
> view’s size and position; therefore, you cannot add additional
> constraints to modify this size or position without introducing
> conflicts.** **If you want to use Auto Layout to dynamically calculate the
> size and position of your view, you must set this property to NO, and
> then provide a non ambiguous, nonconflicting set of constraints for
> the view.** By default, the property is set to YES for any view you
> programmatically create. **If you add views in Interface Builder, the
> system automatically sets this property to NO**.

So, when I came across this issue it was when I was changing the tableview from the contents being a stack view with label and switch into being a label with a UISwitch as the accessory view. The switch was being programmatically created earlier on view load for the container view the table was sitting in and the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints was being set to NO - essentially the same situation that happens when you create the switch in interface builder. The code I was changing then tried to set up constraints but the switch would always bug out and be floating over to the wrong side when you rotated the screen. The solution for me was changing the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property to YES and letting the constraints be created by the view itself. It looks to me like this is a conflicting issue between what this property does on most views and what the accessory view itself tries to handle and if a programmer tries to go in and set things up themselves there seems to not be a good indication of what has gone wrong here. Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Good catch, that sounds like it. Could you share a code example?

Comment: Fixed my issue; Was setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on the view I was adding to `accessoryView` because of programmatically creating constraints. But to fix the view showing up in the top left, had to keep it `true` and only set it to `false` on the subviews of the `accessoryView`.

Answer (score 0):

I can say with some certainty that your constraints are not properly set up. But without seeing the storyboard's constraints, there's no way to say what is broken for sure.